# How to show custom preview for different urls according to dynamic query token

Tags: next.js, preview, dynamic-routing

I have a Next.js 13 app using client-side rendering, hosted on S3 and CloudFront, with a backend on AWS Lambda. I want to show custom preview for different links when shared on social media.

Links format will be like: (e.g., https://example.io/profile/?id=1234562), where the preview shows user-specific details. for person A profile it'll show different name and image, for person be preview will be different.

How to add meta tag for this kind of query token based id and how'd that be rendered?